# Problem on Leetcode submission valid parentheses

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve leetcode problem: [20. Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)

After writing my code I tested several time and the code worked every time. But after submitting, I got a wrong answer notification on "{[]}" case. It said that my code output is false though expected output is true. And I again test my code with that input and I got true as output. Then I test the code using 'playground debug' on leetcode and again I got true as output. I don't understand why my code is working in test cases but not working after submit...

My code is written in python and code is given below:

```
stackArray = []
par = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']':'[',}

def stackPush(p):
    stackArray.append(p)

def stackPop(p):
    if (stackArray[len(stackArray)-1] == par[p]):
        stackArray.pop()
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        if (len(s) == 0):
            return True
        push = ['(', '{', '[']
        pop = [')', '}', ']']


        for i in s:
            if i in push:
                stackPush(i)
            elif  i in pop:
                status = stackPop(i)
                if status == False:
                    return False

        if (len(stackArray)==0):
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize every variable for Leetcode tests. Because Leetcode will run a lot of tests to your method, and if your variable is a global variable and hasn't been initialized, there will be something wrong.

In your codes, stackArray is not an empty Array for your next test case. So you run every test case, it will pass. But when you submit and run several test cases, the result will be wrong.

Now the codes passed.

```
stackArray = []
par = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']':'[',}

def stackPush(p):
    stackArray.append(p)

def stackPop(p):
    if(len(stackArray) == 0):
        return False
    if (stackArray[len(stackArray)-1] == par[p]):
        stackArray.pop()
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Solution:
    def isValid(self,  s):
        while(len(stackArray) > 0):
            stackArray.pop()
        if (len(s) == 0):
            return True
        push = ['(', '{', '[']
        pop = [')', '}', ']']


        for i in s:
            if i in push:
                stackPush(i)
            elif  i in pop:
                status = stackPop(i)
                if status == False:
                    return False

        if (len(stackArray)==0):
            return True
        return False
```